Why take Panpsychism seriously?
This question is about Panpsychism, but it is also a question I have more generally about the requirement for proof in philosophy.
Panpsychism is the view that mentality is fundamental and ubiquitous in the natural world. (SEP)
From my reading, it appears that this view is taken somewhat seriously. This is despite having no empirical evidence and no predictive power.
So what is it based on, then? If all a theory needs to be taken seriously is to fit the data, then couldn't anyone just posit a god to explain any difficult question, and would that be taken seriously? It seems this approach doesn't get us at all closer to any truth, yet apparently it is valid?

Keep in mind that empirical evidence and predictive power is not something that philosophical doctrines are judged on generally, they are not scientific theories. SEP has a whole section on arguments for panpsychism. But the underlying reason is that the main alternatives, physicalism and property dualism, are not doing so well with plausibly explaining a number of mind-body issues at the moment, and those are the ones where panpsychism gets an opening. This is not really analogous to catch-all non-explanations like "God did it".

@Conifold, That is what has me so confused, all these arguments, at least as they appear to me, seem to (very) generally be "Panpsychism fits the data best", but I think my custom-made god fits the data better, but nobody writes papers on my god. I can't see the difference between the two.

@Conifold, "God did it" has never been used as an attempt to solve the  problems you mentioned. However, ontological dualism has, and it should not be ignored as it is the simplest explanation for anyone not working under the religious view that all physical interactions have to be explained by equations.

It's all about simplicity of explanation. The simplest theory that matches observations, with the fewest components and assumptions, is more likely correct. Panpsychism involves only one fundamental kind of substance (mind) which is simpler than dualism that needs two (mind and non-mind). Your custom god would add a complex part to the theory, where panpsychism removes a part from the theory (removes non-mind).

Metaphorically, imagine a scenario where everything anyone has ever observed is "red." "Red-blueists" believe that the world is mostly full of "blue" things that we just can't see, as well as the "red" things that we can. There are also "reddists" who believe everything is red, like the things we can see. If "reddism" explains observations equally well as "red-bluism," then "reddism," which avoids an extra assumption, should be preferred.

@causative My god solves the combination problem, which surely makes up for added complexity. If it doesn't, I could simply adapt my god to consist of only one type of substance, everything that exists is within the mind of my god. There is only god-mind.

@Aph002 How does your god solve the combination problem? Saying a theory accomplishes something does not mean the theory accomplishes that thing. Actually, if you try to figure out how consciousness arises from simple interacting parts you tend to arrive at panpsychism, e.g. see IIT. Second, if you say "there is only god-mind," how is that different from saying "there is only mind"? If it is different, it would be only by introduction of some extra unnecessary attributes that make your god a god, attributes we can get rid of without harming the theory.

@causative Neutral monism adds another thing, violetism, and holds that the red and the blue we experience are both aspects of this third thing.  Violetism needs additional explanations about how red and blue are created by violet, how they sync and interact, and why we cannot experience violet.  All of this is far more complex than red-blueism, that just requires interaction laws between red and blue.

@Dcleve So, this is a reason to reject neutral monism. Reddism would be preferable to both red-blueism and violetism.

@causative But contrary to your example we experience red and have a highly reliable inference to the existence of a blue world that exists whether we red it or not. Reddism, idealism, does not do well in explaining the independence of the blue world. Most panpsychists to day are violetists, not reddists.

@Dcleve We do not have a reliable inference to the existence of a blue world. We have a reliable inference to the existence of a world, and no reason to think it isn't red. I don't care what most panpsychists are; I am a reddist.

@causative hmmm You have described yourself as a physicalist pan psychist.  That is blueism.  We only directly experience red. Blue is an inference.

@Dcleve I say that all that is physical is mind, and vice versa; I am thus both a physicalist and an idealist. In terms of reddism, "red" in the red-blue metaphorical scenario is defined as the category of being that is accessible to subjective experience, and I say that all that is physical is that category of being, which makes me a reddist and not a blueist. A pure "blueist" would be someone who believes there is one category of being that is not the category of being accessible to subjective experience, which imo just is inconsistent with observation (observations being "red").

I could just say I am an idealist, but I prefer to say I am a physicalist first, to emphasize that I accept that the universe operates according to the laws of physics and that objects exist outside the human mind. "Idealist" brings to mind Berkeley's idealism, which I reject, though I am an idealist.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


This question is about Panpsychism, but it is also a question I have more generally about the requirement for proof in philosophy.

There is no requirement for proof in philosophy.  Reasonability, cogency, understanding and mutual understanding, judgment... probably: no "proof" in any strict sense.

From my reading, it appears that this view is taken somewhat seriously. This is despite having no empirical evidence and no predictive power.

Of course it is taken seriously, and with an evidence (and a power) that e.g. comes from meditation, which is personal experience, not just the philosophical and spiritual "studies": rather what ground do you have to reduce the problem to some electric probes or meter sticks and just that?  The burden of your claims to eventually the reduction of all categories to "physical" categories (as if that was even possible), which includes making explicit what you admit as evidence as well as method, is entirely on you.

It seems this approach doesn't get us at all closer to any truth, yet apparently it is valid?

Again: by which definition of "truth" and "valid"?  Do you see how your question is not really a question: you are starting from strong (anti-)metaphysical assumptions and then of course psyche to begin with is just meaningless.

If u allow that things like meditation speak to an actual reifyable realm you get a very different direction than if you're a hard headed physicalist!! (Vide. neighboring question on memory) Anyways +1

This has been very helpful, and I see my error in taking physicalism as a default position. However, could you expand on: "all categories to "physical" categories (as if that was even possible)". How can you or anybody, with such little information, make such a large claim? (I interpret it as you saying physicalism is not possible). Is this not the same mistake as someone saying "life could not possibly emerge from non-life within physicalism". Aren't these the same claims physicalism has been defeating time and time again? i.e. god/spiritualism in the gaps? Thanks.

"The reduction of all categories to physical categories" is (AIUI) just what Physicalism is, i.e. by definition.  (Do you have any objection to that?)  And of course Physicalism is possible, indeed it exists: my "as if that was even possible" refers to the possibility of justifying that reduction.

Philosophy is about truth not proof. However, there is an interesting crossover between science and philosophy on this. Quantum physics has thrown up intriguing possibilities here, such as quantum entanglement. So science may contribute to the proof you seek. In any case, panpsychism is worthy of consideration. It is a serious view espoused for millenia.

Can you point to any physics research that suggests that entanglement is in some way related to panpsychism?

Quantum entanglement suggests the possibility of communication between fundamental particles at vast distances. Therefore, the particles are aware of one another's state. This awareness can be seen as fundamental consciousness, The matter is in a crossover area between physics and philosophy. It is a work in progress.
